# Wrong text being shown in a template file

Tags: theming

When I add text in Hebrew inside html.tpl.php, it shows me strange characters instead of the ones I am expecting.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the encoding of new files to utf-8 in your text-editor. The image below is on Notepad++. There should be a similar setting in your text editor.

[image]

To test if you got it right, create an HTML/PHP file with the Hebrew text outside of Drupal first.

For Notepad, `Save As` and select `UTF-8` as the `Encoding`.

[image]

Also, make sure you have the following line in the `<head>` tag of your HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: I added a 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

but still shows me question marks

Comment: I added an image about what I meant.

Comment: im using the regular notepad ... and also that happens in any template i have on my system out side the drupal its works ok

Comment: I added information for saving to `UTF-8` in Notepad.

Comment: Check if you have the meta tag I mentioned above.

Comment: i have it... tho thats happen in every template i try to change

Comment: Do the Hebrew characters appear correctly before you edit then using Notepad?

Comment: im doing everything in notepad when im uploading the html to the server (not drupal) you can see the hebrew . when im adding the html to the drupal i see question marks

Comment: You should really save out without the BOM.  Having the BOM inside files, especially any PHP, can cause some weird problems.  It can also cause errors when aggregating CSS.

Comment: Agree about the without BOM part (too lazy to switch back to Windows and get a screenshot).

Comment: Replaced it with proper image.